# Show Parse Object data in a TextView

Tags: android, parse-platform, textview

obj is a string with the Id for a specific object in my parse database. I want to get individual rows values and show them in a text view. The below code is what I've got. Not sure why but the query alwasy seems tho return empty. Thus my strings restName,restCuisine,etc all have their initialized values only i.e their values aren't changing because of my query. Any help would be appreciated

```
public class SingleRestraunt extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    TextView resteName, resteCuisine, resteLocation, resteAddress;
    String restName = "nothing", obj, restCuisine = "nothing",
            restLocation = "nothing", restAddress = "nothing";
    Double Lang = 19.144378, Long = 72.837135;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_restraunt);
        resteName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntName);
        resteCuisine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntCuisine);
        resteLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntLocation);
        resteAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restrauntAddress);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        obj = i.getStringExtra("restId");
        getDetails(obj);

    }

    private void getDetails(final String obj) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("resdb");
        query.getInBackground(obj, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    restName = object.getString("name");
                    restCuisine = object.getString("cuisine");
                    restLocation = object.getString("location");
                    restAddress = object.getString("address");
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        prepareMap(Lang, Long);
        addData();

    }

    public void addData() {

        resteName.setText(restName);
        resteCuisine.setText(restCuisine);
        resteLocation.setText(restLocation);
        resteAddress.setText(restAddress);
    }

    public void prepareMap(Double Lang, Double Long) {
        final LatLng REST = new LatLng(Lang, Long);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(REST)
                .title("Here"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(REST, 15));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.single_restraunt, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not correct to call `prepareMap(Lang, Long)` and `addData()` after to the call `query.getInBackground(...)` because "In background" means in a different Thread. You should reorder your calls like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("resdb");
    query.getInBackground(obj, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                restName = object.getString("name");
                restCuisine = object.getString("cuisine");
                restLocation = object.getString("location");
                restAddress = object.getString("address");
                // Update your info after to get the rest info
                prepareMap(Lang, Long);
                addData();
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope this help you!